Show that $X_n+Y_n$ doesnt converge in probability to any random variable
Let $X$ be a random variable with a discrete distribution  $P(X = 1) = P(X = −1) = 1/2$ and $X_{n}:= X$ a $Y_{n}:= (−1)^{n}X$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Show that $X_{n}+Y_{n}$ does not converge in probability and not even in distribution to any random variable.
I have that $X_{n}+Y_{n}=0$ for odd $n$ and $X_{n}+Y_{n}=2X$ for even $n$. Then I tried this: We take some random variable $Z$, have $P(|Xn+Yn-Z|>\varepsilon)$ and separate it into three cases: $P(|2-Z|>\varepsilon)$, $P(|-2-Z|>\varepsilon)$ and $P(|-Z|>\varepsilon)$
However, I am not really sure how to continue or how to prove it for all random variables. If we want to show that it does not converge in probability, we can find only one epsilon such that the probability is not 0 - but what can we do in this case?

One basic observation is that if a sequence does converge in probability or in distribution to something, then any subsequence of it must converge to the same unique thing. In this case, the odd and even subsequences converge to two different objects and hence the limit is not unique. That is enough to say that convergence in probability or in distribution does not hold.

Set $Z_n=X_n+Y_n$. As you Said $Z_{2k+1}=0$ whereas $Z_{2k}=2X$ for all $k$. Since $Z_{2k+1}=0$ for all $k$, if it converges in probability it converges to $0$. Moreover, $|Z_{2k}|=2$, and thus $\mathbb P\{|Z_{2k}|>1\}=1$. Therefore, it won't converges to anything in probability.
A similar arguments works to prove that it doesn't converges in distribution.

$\mathbb P{|Z_{2k}|=2}=1$ and $\mathbb P{|Z_{2k+1}|=0}=1$ would convince me there is no convergence of any kind
